# ngRepeat div get commented out when i see from the browser inspector

Tags: java, html, angularjs, eclipse, angularjs-ng-repeat

[this is my html code.but the ngRepeat div show as commented in browser inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVkS.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMVkS.jpg)

<

```
html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="script/bootstrap.css">
<script src="script/tuto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body style="padding: 50px"  ng-controller="ctrl">

    <div>



        <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchFor"
                size="20" />
        </p>


        <div class="album panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{ album.title }}
                <div style="float: right">{{ album.date }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">{{ album.description }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchFor"
                size="20" />
        </p>


        <div class="album panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{ album.title }}
                <div style="float: right">{{ album.date }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">{{ album.description }}</div>
        </div>



        <h3>Add new Album</h3>

        <div class="album panel panel-success" ng-repeat="album in albums">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                {{ album.title }}
                <div style="float: right">{{ album.date }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="description">{{ album.description }}</div>
        </div>





</body>
</html>
```

`enter code here`

This is the HTML code.it's also have the script part for angularJs.but the ngRepaet div showed as commented in browser inspector

Comment: where is ng-app of you? And you should write script in another file and include it in html

Comment: @ThanhTùng i'm doing this watching a tutorial..it done as this.after that i create separe js file and add the ng app also..but the same result

Comment: @ThanhTùng check my new code.i edited it. wrote script in another file..but same result
THis is my script file code

var myModal = angular.module('myApp', []);

myModal.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
 


    $scope.albums = [ 
        { name: 'thailand1210', title: 'Surfing in Thailand', date: '2012-10-01', description: 'So hot!' },
        { name: 'australia1207', title: 'Wedding in Australia', date: '2012-07-31', description: 'So many kangaroos and koalas!' }
    ];

 $scope.addAlbum = function(new_album) {
  $scope.albums.push(new_album);

 };

});

Comment: your problem is you include file script above angular.js . include below and problem will solved

Comment: Check my answer . And if problem solved . Please accept my answer

Comment: @Thanh i added a photo as a answer.check that.thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write script in another file and add `ng-app`
Here is plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/yvJGX52osH9eTJggexec?p=preview

your problem is you include file script above angular.js . include below and problem will solved

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="script/bootstrap.css"> 
<script> type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.js"></script> 
<script> type="text/javascript" src="script/angular.min.js"></script> <script> type="text/javascript" src="script/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
 <script src="script/tuto.js"></script> //include below
```

Comment: Thank you. it will slove the problem..but now angulajs not working.. it shows as this "{{ album.title }}". your plunker example also have the same problem..can you suggest any answer for it

Comment: Can you add img for json file

Answer (score 0):

[@Thanh check this..this is the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnPeb.jpg)

Comment: okay . Please accept my answer by tick v in leftside my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer